# I can't run 'npm run dev' since Laravel updated with Vite

Tags: laravel, compiler-errors, vite

Taylor Otwell announced that new Laravel projects now will run with Vite and that Vite is installed by default. I can't seem to be able to run dev environment `npm run dev`

I installed new laravel project, installed Laravel JetStream with SSR and teams support hit the 'npm install command'.

Every time I run `npm run dev` it shows this:

[image: error]

And if I open the local link, it shows this:

[image: localhost]

Why can't I user `npm run dev` and compile my files?

This is package.json for my brand new laravel app

```js
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build && vite build --ssr"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.11.0",
        "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3": "^0.6.0",
        "@inertiajs/progress": "^0.2.7",
        "@inertiajs/server": "^0.1.0",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.2",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.3",
        "@vue/server-renderer": "^3.2.31",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
        "axios": "^0.25",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.2.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.4.14",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.0",
        "vite": "^2.9.11",
        "vue": "^3.2.31"
    }
}
```

and if I try hitting 'vite' in the terminal I get this:

[image: vite error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue, I did the following and **it finally worked!**

**I did:**

- Upgraded my `Laravel Project` to `Latest (v9.19.0)`. Infact i upgraded all my packages to latest one too.
- Remove the `node_modules` and install the dependency using `npm install`
- Make sure you follow the [upgrade guides](https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/UPGRADE.md) properly.
- Run the server using `php artisan serve`
- And run the dev server using `npm run dev`

If you done properly, it should start the dev server and all your javascript code should compile. (If it succeed, you will see the desired output.)

> I fixed the issue in the above steps.

Comment: Op has created a brand new laravel install, so upgrade guides shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Same problem for me. Fresh new installation of Laravel Sail. Everything fits the upgrade guide steps. I can see just a blank page, but source code shows it is working, just inertia component is not loaded or something like that.

Answer (score 17):

If you don't want to use `vite` but `mix` instead in your new laravel project, you can just get the usual behavior of `npm run dev` back with the following changes:

1. Install Laravel Mix (because by the new installation it is not there anymore):

```
npm install --save-dev laravel-mix
```

2. Create a `webpack.mix.js` file, if it is not there, and make sure it has the following content:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mix Asset Management
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
| for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
| file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files. 
|
*/

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
       //
]);
```

3. Update `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
-     "dev": "vite",
-     "build": "vite build"
+     "dev": "npm run development",
+     "development": "mix",
+     "watch": "mix watch",
+     "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
+     "hot": "mix watch --hot",
+     "prod": "npm run production",
+     "production": "mix --production"
}
```

4. Remove vite helper functions (if they are there):

```
- import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';

  createInertiaApp({
      title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
-     resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
+     resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}.vue`),
      setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
          return createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
              .use(plugin)
              .mixin({ methods: { route } })
              .mount(el);
      },
});
```

5. Update environment valiables (in .env, `VITE_` prefix to `MIX_`):

```
- VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
- VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
+ MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
+ MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

6. Remove Vite and the laravel Plugin

```
npm remove vite laravel-vite-plugin
```

7. Remove the Vite config file:

```
rm vite.config.js
```

8. Remove these paths from .gitignore:

```
- /public/build
- /storage/ssr
```

If you created some code already with vite, you must have some more changes in your blade files, check out [this article](https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/UPGRADE.md#migrating-from-vite-to-laravel-mix). But if it is a new project, you just good to go.

Comment: you saved my project, thank you @Gabesz Juhász

Comment: Excellent answer to rollback to mix, but Vite is actually great and made the default for a reason. I recommend you create a migration branch to make your project work with Vite.

Comment: Is there I could do the same if I am using Reactjs instead of Vue?

Comment: certainly yes, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Ok, tried this after hours and hours trying to get my brand new Laravel project running. Now instead of getting "sh: 1: vite: not found" I instead get "sh: 1: mix: not found" when I try to run npm run dev.  Why can't just Laravel work out of the box???

Answer (score 11):

For anyone experiencing the problem:

With Vite, running `npm run dev` will only build your frontend and start watching any changes to your code to rebuild automatically.

To actually start your server, you need to run `php artisan serve` in a separate command window.

Source (See **With Laravel** section): https://laravel-vite.dev/guide/essentials/development.html#with-laravel

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue, but none of the mentioned solutions worked for me. Instead I saw an issue with the <script> src's in the head-section of the rendered html.

[screenshot of script src's buggy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4inja.png)

Added in vite.config.js the following code which **solved** the issue.

```
server: {
    hmr: {
        host: 'localhost',
    },
}
```

*Edit:*
The issue was reported in [laravel's vite-plugin repo](https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/issues/28) and it will be fixed with [this PR](https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/pull/42)

Answer (score 1):

Vite needs an updated node version.

You can download the latest [node version](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) then run `npm install` and `npm run dev`

To create the server you can use `php artisan serve`

Comment: on https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project page is writing :  `Vite requires Node.js version 14.18+, 16+…`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laragon as a local deployment you can set the --host flag to the virtual host url of the app ,it worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

.env :

APP_URL=http://localhost:8000

welcome.blade.php :

```
<head>

<title>my project</title>

@vite(['/resources/js/app.js', '/resources/css/app.css'])
```

Answer (score -2):

1. Change `APP_URL=http://localhost:8000` in `.env` file
2. Use `php artisan serve` to create server
3. Use `npm run dev`